# Вывод изображения на форму из базы данных

Tags: c#, sqlite

Я хочу реализовать вывод изображения из базы данных на SQLite на PictureBox по кнопке, но не знаю как.

Comment: Всё зависит от того, как изображения хранятся в БД.

Answer (score 3):

Если файлы изображений не слишком велики (меньше 10Mb), то их можно хранить в столбце типа `Blob`.
Создадим БД с такой таблицей

[image: схема таблицы]

Создадим такой класс модели

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Image Pic { get; set; }

    public void SetPicFromBlob(Stream blob)
    {
        Pic = Image.FromStream(blob);
    }
}
```

Для работы с БД напишем такой класс

```
class SQLiteDataContext : IDataContext
{
    private const string _PathToFile_ = @"Data\imagesdb.sqlite";

    /// <summary>
    /// Создание соединения с файлом БД
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = _PathToFile_;

        return new SQLiteConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение всего списка картинок
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<List<Picture>> GetPictures()
    {
        var result = new List<Picture>();

        using (SQLiteConnection cn = GetConnection())
        using (SQLiteCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM images;";
            await cn.OpenAsync();

            using (var reader = await cm.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var picture = GetPictureFromRow(reader);
                        result.Add(picture);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Создание экземпляра Picture
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Picture GetPictureFromRow(DbDataReader reader)
    {
        var result = new Picture
        {
            Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
            Name = reader.GetString(1),
            Description = reader.GetString(2)
        };

        result.SetPicFromBlob(reader.GetStream(3));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Код в форме такой

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IDataContext _data;
    private BindingSource _bsPics = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Text = "Пример получения изображений из SQLite";
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        //установка привязок
        SetBindings();
        //загрузка данных
        LoadData();
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        //тип источника
        _bsPics.DataSource = typeof(List<Picture>);

        //привязка к ListBox
        _listBoxNames.ValueMember = nameof(Picture.Id);
        _listBoxNames.DisplayMember = nameof(Picture.Name);
        _listBoxNames.DataSource = _bsPics;

        //привязка к PictureBox
        _pictureBoxOutput.DataBindings.Add("Image", _bsPics, nameof(Picture.Pic));

        //привязка к TextBox
        _textBoxDesc.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsPics, nameof(Picture.Description));
    }

    private async void LoadData()
    {
        //тестовая БД
        //_data = new TestDataContext();

        //реальная БД
        _data = new SQLiteDataContext();

        //получаем данные и заполняем источник привязки
        var pics = await _data.GetPictures();
        pics.ForEach(p => _bsPics.Add(p));
    }
}
```

И работает это так

[image: работа примера]

Пример находится [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/ImagesFromDb).

Answer (score 2):

Изображения можно хранить в бинарном виде, но так делать не стоит. Из PNG перевести в бинарный вид, записать в бд. Взять из бд бинарный вид, преобразовать в PNG.

Решение:

1) В БД сохранить путь изображения ("~/img/1.png...") (картинка находится у тебя на ПК, например в папке с приложением)

2) Взять картинку по пути. (указать в PictureBox путь к картинке)