# Загрузка фото из бд и вставка в ImageButton

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Храню фотографии в базе данных как двоичные данные (вроде бы только так и можно загрузить фото в бд). Мне нужно из бд (sql server) вытащить фото и отобразить его в ImageButton.

```
private static Image GetImageBinaryFromDb()
        {
            List<byte[]> iScreen = new List<byte[]>();
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxx; User Id= xxxx; Password=xxxx;"))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
                sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
                sqlCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT [xxxxx] FROM [xxxx] WHERE [xxxx] = 0";
                SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                byte[] iTrimByte = null;
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    iTrimByte = (byte[])sqlReader["xxxx"];
                    iScreen.Add(iTrimByte);
                }
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
           
            byte[] imageData = iScreen[0];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
            Image newImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return newImage;

        }
```

Метод достает из бд массив байтов и приводит его к типу Image (хотя это наверное конченная практика - применять обычные десктопные библиотеки шарпа к андроид приложению). Проблема в том, что ни тип Image, ни byte[] не подходят ни для одного метода для установки изображения (по типу myimageview.SetImageResource/SetImageDrawable и т.д.). Может есть какие-то особенные методы для андроида, а то в крайнем случае прийдется загрузить фото в сам проект.

Comment: проект на Xamarin.Android

Comment: Вообще-то у `reader` есть метод `GetStream()`. [Смотрите пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991532/222542) на работу с Sqlite, но для вашего случая это тоже подойдет.