# Как выгрузить изображение из postgres в picturebox c#

Tags: c#, postgresql

Я пытаюсь получить изображение из postgresql с помощью C #.

В таблице есть колонка: photo(bytea)

Вот код получения фото из базы

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
{
    string sQL = "SELECT photo from picturetable WHERE id = 65";
    using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sQL, conn))
    {
        byte[] productImageByte = null;
        conn.Open();
        var rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.Read())
        {
            productImageByte = (byte[])rdr[0];
        }
        rdr.Close();
        if (productImageByte != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream productImageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(productImageByte))
            {
                ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
                pictureBox1.Image = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(productImageByte) as System.Drawing.Image;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код для вставки изображения работает нормально, но я не могу показать это изображение в окне с картинками.

Вот такая ошибка :

Parameter is not valid

Хееелп!

Comment: Вам не нужен `MemoryStream`, т.к. у ридера есть метод `reader.GetStream()`. Смотрите пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991532/222542 хоть там и Sqlite, но сути это не меняет.

Comment: Нужно знать, как изображение было записано в БД, чтобы можно было совершить обратный процесс.

Comment: _Хееелп!_ - что это?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov зис из инглиш версион оф "памагииите" виз кирилик чарактерс транслитерейшн.